# Modifying javascript class attributes

Tags: javascript, object-oriented-analysis

What i am trying to do here is, I have the following class Session

```
function Session(){
    this.accounts = {};
    this.setupAccounts = function(res){
        this.accounts = res;
        log(res);
        log(this.accounts);
    };

    this.test = function(){
        log(this.accounts);
    };
}
```

The class Session has an attribute accounts, which will keep store certain data. But in order to initialize it, i initialize it as an empty object.

Next I call the method setupAccounts to modify the value of accounts. For example, I read a file, load it's data and then store that data inside accounts.

But I am having scope problems.

For example the following code :

```
var session = new Session();
var user_account_path = '/adata/user_accounts.json';
loadJsonFile(user_account_path)
     .then(session.setupAccounts);
session.test();
```

So what i am doing in the code above is fetching the contents of a file as a Json Object and then I am passing that data to the method setupAccounts in order to store that data in the variable accounts. But my output looks like the following:

```
Object {arjrule3: Object}  // printing the json object read from file
Object {arjrule3: Object}  // locally changed value of accounts
console.log(session.accounts) // printing global value of accounts
{} // value has not changed.
```

What am i doing wrong? Why isn't the value for accounts changing for the object session ?

Something Funny just happened, if i write the code as the following:

```
var session = new Session();
var user_account_path = '/adata/user_accounts.json';
loadJsonFile(user_account_path)
   .then(function(res){
      session.setupAccounts(res);  // Change Here
   });
```

Output:

```
Object {arjrule3: Object}
Object {arjrule3: Object}
session.accounts
Object {arjrule3: Object}  // works! Why ?
```

It works, why is it so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var session = new Session();
var user_account_path = '/adata/user_accounts.json';
loadJsonFile(user_account_path)
 .then(session.setupAccounts);
session.test();
```

In the above example you're just passing the function "setupAccounts" as the callback. You would need to bind it first e.g.

```
var session = new Session();
var user_account_path = '/adata/user_accounts.json';
loadJsonFile(user_account_path)
 .then(session.setupAccounts.bind(session));
session.test();
```

The other example you've added works because you're calling the "setupAccounts" function on the session object, not just passing a reference to it.